# Video Exporting Black/White Odd Image Landsat 4/5 and other Landsats in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat, time-series, corrupt

I am able to get variations of this code to work with Sentinel images, and with a heatmap image collection from Yale. However, I have tried with every landsat collection, and I always get videos that are frames of blocky black and white images. Here is my latest fail (the top section is the imported stuff, which in GEE's Code Editor appears as three lines):

```
var YS = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* locked: true */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-111.28026903308462, 45.20261943933138],
          [-111.28026903308462, 43.99011472819624],
          [-108.90310228503775, 43.99011472819624],
          [-108.90310228503775, 45.20261943933138]]], null, false),
    L4 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2"),
    L5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2");

Map.centerObject(YS, 9)
var L4time=L4.filterDate('1988-04-15','1988-12-15').filterBounds(YS).select('SR_B3','SR_B2','SR_B1')
var L5time=L5.filterDate('1988-04-15','1988-12-15').filterBounds(YS).select('SR_B3','SR_B2','SR_B1')
var createTrueColor = function(image){
  return ee.Image(image).visualize({
    bands: ['SR_B3','SR_B2','SR_B1'],
    min: 0,
    max: 256,
    gamma: 1.4
  })
}
var merged=L4time.merge(L5time).sort('DATE_ACQUIRED').map(function(merged){return merged.clip(YS).uint8()}).map(createTrueColor)
print(merged)
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: merged,
  description: "Yellowstone",
  folder:"VideoExports",
  framesPerSecond:1,
  scale: 30,
  })
```

I get the same result, whether or not I use createTrueColor. I found the createTrueColor function from another community question re Landsat7.

When I run this on Sentinel (adjusting where necessary, such as band names), it works.

I am trying to get a time series of the 1988 Yellowstone fires.

Comment: here is a link to videos. St. Louis Sprawl was an attempt to combine every landsat collection, then take the least cloudy image from each summer, and then run a time-series, with (if i recall my code correctly) false color for the early landsats. no reason to get into that code, just that the video output has a similar problem to the Yellowstone videos. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jqs_P4-n6WcU04OmGg4Lom6E9HJ6ZsuO?usp=share_link